# Getting started with BLE -> NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I've got a problem with this tutorial from the Book "Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy".

I only want to scan for BLE devices and post the results via logcat. But anytime I do start the scan, the app shut down and give me a NullPointerException (See Logcat below). For this example I'm using the BleWrapper Class, but I also try to set up BLE Scan without it in another app. But it is always the same error... NullPointerException...
I also tried out 2 different demo apps, import them into my Android studio(v1.1) and they perform well. But if I try to write the same code in its own activity it will crash with this error.

I guess it's something wrong with the callback, or the scanning-method, maybe I forget some reference?

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.oliver.blebuch;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private BleWrapper mBleWrapper = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("tag", "Test");
        mBleWrapper = new BleWrapper(this, new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null()
        {
            @Override
            public void uiDeviceFound(final BluetoothDevice device,
                                      final int rssi,
                                      final byte[] scanRecord)
            {
                Log.d("tag", "uiDeviceFound: "+device.getName()+", "+rssi+", "+scanRecord.toString());
            }
        });

        if(mBleWrapper.checkBleHardwareAvailable() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No BLE-compatible hardware detected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        //check for Bluetooth enabled on each resume
        if (mBleWrapper.isBtEnabled() == false)
        {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        mBleWrapper.disconnect();
        mBleWrapper.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_scan:
                mBleWrapper.startScanning();
                break;
            case R.id.action_stop:
                mBleWrapper.stopScanning();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-26 10:28:49.986  26288-26288/com.example.oliver.blebuch D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-26 10:28:53.236  26288-26288/com.example.oliver.blebuch W/dalvikvm﹕ method Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
03-26 10:28:53.266  26288-26288/com.example.oliver.blebuch D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-26 10:28:54.366  26288-26288/com.example.oliver.blebuch D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-26 10:28:54.366  26288-26288/com.example.oliver.blebuch W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41783da0)
03-26 10:28:54.376  26288-26288/com.example.oliver.blebuch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.oliver.blebuch, PID: 26288
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.oliver.blebuch.BleWrapper.startScanning(BleWrapper.java:79)
            at com.example.oliver.blebuch.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:78)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2708)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:556)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:187)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1495)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3453)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4816)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

BLE Wrapper Class:

```
package com.example.oliver.blebuch;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class BleWrapper {
    /* defines (in milliseconds) how often RSSI should be updated */
    private static final int RSSI_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL = 1500; // 1.5 seconds

    /* callback object through which we are returning results to the caller */
    private BleWrapperUiCallbacks mUiCallback = null;
    /* define NULL object for UI callbacks */
    private static final BleWrapperUiCallbacks NULL_CALLBACK = new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null(); 

    /* creates BleWrapper object, set its parent activity and callback object */
    public BleWrapper(Activity parent, BleWrapperUiCallbacks callback) {
        this.mParent = parent;
        mUiCallback = callback;
        if(mUiCallback == null) mUiCallback = NULL_CALLBACK;
    }

    public BluetoothManager           getManager() { return mBluetoothManager; }
    public BluetoothAdapter           getAdapter() { return mBluetoothAdapter; }
    public BluetoothDevice            getDevice()  { return mBluetoothDevice; }
    public BluetoothGatt              getGatt()    { return mBluetoothGatt; }
    public BluetoothGattService       getCachedService() { return mBluetoothSelectedService; }
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getCachedServices() { return mBluetoothGattServices; }
    public boolean                    isConnected() { return mConnected; }

    /* run test and check if this device has BT and BLE hardware available */
    public boolean checkBleHardwareAvailable() {
        // First check general Bluetooth Hardware:
        // get BluetoothManager...
        final BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) mParent.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if(manager == null) return false;
        // .. and then get adapter from manager
        final BluetoothAdapter adapter = manager.getAdapter();
        if(adapter == null) return false;

        // and then check if BT LE is also available
        boolean hasBle = mParent.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
        return hasBle;
    }    


    /* before any action check if BT is turned ON and enabled for us 
     * call this in onResume to be always sure that BT is ON when Your
     * application is put into the foreground */
    public boolean isBtEnabled() {
        final BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) mParent.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if(manager == null) return false;

        final BluetoothAdapter adapter = manager.getAdapter();
        if(adapter == null) return false;

        return adapter.isEnabled();
    }

    /* start scanning for BT LE devices around */
    public void startScanning() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mDeviceFoundCallback);
    }

    /* stops current scanning */
    public void stopScanning() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mDeviceFoundCallback); 
    }

    /* initialize BLE and get BT Manager & Adapter */
    public boolean initialize() {
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mParent.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;        
    }

    /* connect to the device with specified address */
    public boolean connect(final String deviceAddress) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || deviceAddress == null) return false;
        mDeviceAddress = deviceAddress;

        // check if we need to connect from scratch or just reconnect to previous device
        if(mBluetoothGatt != null && mBluetoothGatt.getDevice().getAddress().equals(deviceAddress)) {
            // just reconnect
            return mBluetoothGatt.connect();
        }
        else {
            // connect from scratch
            // get BluetoothDevice object for specified address
            mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
            if (mBluetoothDevice == null) {
                // we got wrong address - that device is not available!
                return false;
            }
            // connect with remote device
            mBluetoothGatt = mBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(mParent, false, mBleCallback);
        }
        return true;
    }  

    /* disconnect the device. It is still possible to reconnect to it later with this Gatt client */
    public void disconnect() {
        if(mBluetoothGatt != null) mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
         mUiCallback.uiDeviceDisconnected(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice);
    }

    /* close GATT client completely */
    public void close() {
        if(mBluetoothGatt != null) mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }    

    /* request new RSSi value for the connection*/
    public void readPeriodicalyRssiValue(final boolean repeat) {
        mTimerEnabled = repeat;
        // check if we should stop checking RSSI value
        if(mConnected == false || mBluetoothGatt == null || mTimerEnabled == false) {
            mTimerEnabled = false;
            return;
        }

        mTimerHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothGatt == null ||
                   mBluetoothAdapter == null ||
                   mConnected == false)
                {
                    mTimerEnabled = false;
                    return;
                }

                // request RSSI value
                mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
                // add call it once more in the future
                readPeriodicalyRssiValue(mTimerEnabled);
            }
        }, RSSI_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL);
    }    

    /* starts monitoring RSSI value */
    public void startMonitoringRssiValue() {
        readPeriodicalyRssiValue(true);
    }

    /* stops monitoring of RSSI value */
    public void stopMonitoringRssiValue() {
        readPeriodicalyRssiValue(false);
    }

    /* request to discover all services available on the remote devices
     * results are delivered through callback object */
    public void startServicesDiscovery() {
        if(mBluetoothGatt != null) mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
    }

    /* gets services and calls UI callback to handle them
     * before calling getServices() make sure service discovery is finished! */
    public void getSupportedServices() {
        if(mBluetoothGattServices != null && mBluetoothGattServices.size() > 0) mBluetoothGattServices.clear();
        // keep reference to all services in local array:
        if(mBluetoothGatt != null) mBluetoothGattServices = mBluetoothGatt.getServices();

        mUiCallback.uiAvailableServices(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, mBluetoothGattServices);
    }

    /* get all characteristic for particular service and pass them to the UI callback */
    public void getCharacteristicsForService(final BluetoothGattService service) {
        if(service == null) return;
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> chars = null;

        chars = service.getCharacteristics();       
        mUiCallback.uiCharacteristicForService(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, service, chars);
        // keep reference to the last selected service
        mBluetoothSelectedService = service;
    }

    /* request to fetch newest value stored on the remote device for particular characteristic */
    public void requestCharacteristicValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) return;

        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(ch);
        // new value available will be notified in Callback Object
    }

    /* get characteristic's value (and parse it for some types of characteristics) 
     * before calling this You should always update the value by calling requestCharacteristicValue() */
    public void getCharacteristicValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null || ch == null) return;

        byte[] rawValue = ch.getValue();
        String strValue = null;
        int intValue = 0;

        // lets read and do real parsing of some characteristic to get meaningful value from it 
        UUID uuid = ch.getUuid();

        if(uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT)) { // heart rate
            // follow https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
            // first check format used by the device - it is specified in bit 0 and tells us if we should ask for index 1 (and uint8) or index 2 (and uint16)
            int index = ((rawValue[0] & 0x01) == 1) ? 2 : 1;
            // also we need to define format
            int format = (index == 1) ? BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8 : BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            // now we have everything, get the value
            intValue = ch.getIntValue(format, index);
            strValue = intValue + " bpm"; // it is always in bpm units
        }
        else if (uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT) || // manufacturer name string
                 uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.MODEL_NUMBER_STRING) || // model number string)
                 uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.FIRMWARE_REVISION_STRING)) // firmware revision string
        {
            // follow https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.manufacturer_name_string.xml etc.
            // string value are usually simple utf8s string at index 0
            strValue = ch.getStringValue(0);
        }
        else if(uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.APPEARANCE)) { // appearance
            // follow: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml
            intValue  = ((int)rawValue[1]) << 8;
            intValue += rawValue[0];
            strValue = BleNamesResolver.resolveAppearance(intValue);
        }
        else if(uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.BODY_SENSOR_LOCATION)) { // body sensor location
            // follow: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.body_sensor_location.xml
            intValue = rawValue[0];
            strValue = BleNamesResolver.resolveHeartRateSensorLocation(intValue);
        }
        else if(uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.BATTERY_LEVEL)) { // battery level
            // follow: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml
            intValue = rawValue[0];
            strValue = "" + intValue + "% battery level";
        }        
        else {
            // not known type of characteristic, so we need to handle this in "general" way
            // get first four bytes and transform it to integer
            intValue = 0;
            if(rawValue.length > 0) intValue = (int)rawValue[0];
            if(rawValue.length > 1) intValue = intValue + ((int)rawValue[1] << 8); 
            if(rawValue.length > 2) intValue = intValue + ((int)rawValue[2] << 8); 
            if(rawValue.length > 3) intValue = intValue + ((int)rawValue[3] << 8); 

            if (rawValue.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(rawValue.length);
                for(byte byteChar : rawValue) {
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%c", byteChar));
                }
                strValue = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }

        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date());
        mUiCallback.uiNewValueForCharacteristic(mBluetoothGatt,
                                                mBluetoothDevice,
                                                mBluetoothSelectedService,
                                                ch,
                                                strValue,
                                                intValue,
                                                rawValue,
                                                timestamp);
    }    

    /* reads and return what what FORMAT is indicated by characteristic's properties
     * seems that value makes no sense in most cases */
    public int getValueFormat(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch) {
        int properties = ch.getProperties();

        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SFLOAT & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SFLOAT;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT16 & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT16;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT32 & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT32;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT8 & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT8;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16 & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32 & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
        if((BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8 & properties) != 0) return BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;

        return 0;
    }

    /* set new value for particular characteristic */
    public void writeDataToCharacteristic(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, final byte[] dataToWrite) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null || ch == null) return;

        // first set it locally....
        ch.setValue(dataToWrite);
        // ... and then "commit" changes to the peripheral
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(ch);
    }

    /* enables/disables notification for characteristic */
    public void setNotificationForCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, boolean enabled) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) return;

        boolean success = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(ch, enabled);
        if(!success) {
            Log.e("------", "Seting proper notification status for characteristic failed!");
        }

        // This is also sometimes required (e.g. for heart rate monitors) to enable notifications/indications
        // see: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = ch.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        if(descriptor != null) {
            byte[] val = enabled ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;
            descriptor.setValue(val);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }

    /* defines callback for scanning results */
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mDeviceFoundCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
            mUiCallback.uiDeviceFound(device, rssi, scanRecord);
        }
    };      

    /* callbacks called for any action on particular Ble Device */
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mBleCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                mConnected = true;
                mUiCallback.uiDeviceConnected(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice);

                // now we can start talking with the device, e.g.
                mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
                // response will be delivered to callback object!

                // in our case we would also like automatically to call for services discovery
                startServicesDiscovery();

                // and we also want to get RSSI value to be updated periodically
                startMonitoringRssiValue();
            }
            else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                mConnected = false;
                mUiCallback.uiDeviceDisconnected(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // now, when services discovery is finished, we can call getServices() for Gatt
                getSupportedServices();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status)
        {
            // we got response regarding our request to fetch characteristic value
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // and it success, so we can get the value
                getCharacteristicValue(characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
        {
            // characteristic's value was updated due to enabled notification, lets get this value
            // the value itself will be reported to the UI inside getCharacteristicValue
            getCharacteristicValue(characteristic);
            // also, notify UI that notification are enabled for particular characteristic
            mUiCallback.uiGotNotification(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, mBluetoothSelectedService, characteristic);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            String deviceName = gatt.getDevice().getName();
            String serviceName = BleNamesResolver.resolveServiceName(characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            String charName = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(characteristic.getUuid().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            String description = "Device: " + deviceName + " Service: " + serviceName + " Characteristic: " + charName;

            // we got response regarding our request to write new value to the characteristic
            // let see if it failed or not
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                 mUiCallback.uiSuccessfulWrite(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, mBluetoothSelectedService, characteristic, description);
            }
            else {
                 mUiCallback.uiFailedWrite(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, mBluetoothSelectedService, characteristic, description + " STATUS = " + status);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // we got new value of RSSI of the connection, pass it to the UI
                 mUiCallback.uiNewRssiAvailable(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, rssi);
            }
        };
    };

    private Activity mParent = null;    
    private boolean mConnected = false;
    private String mDeviceAddress = "";

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothDevice  mBluetoothDevice = null;
    private BluetoothGatt    mBluetoothGatt = null;
    private BluetoothGattService mBluetoothSelectedService = null;
    private List<BluetoothGattService> mBluetoothGattServices = null;   

    private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
    private boolean mTimerEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: what is there at line number 79 of BleWrapper.java. Show us more code, also add BleWrapper's start scanning

Comment: At Line 79 in the BleWrapperclass is the Start scan routine                   /* start scanning for BT LE devices around */
 public void startScanning() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mDeviceFoundCallback);
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your `startScanning` method of `BleWrapper` class to below code and it should work.

```
public void startScanning() {
   if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
     mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

   mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mDeviceFoundCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mBluetoothAdapter` is `null` and therefore the `startLeScan` method call fails

Hope this helps :)